# Error response in client side only in firefox

Tags: typescript, firefox, angular-cli, angular11

I am facing an issue when I get string data from asp.net core API using angular 11 Like below

```
Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:51857/api/Account/GetRoleName/username@mail.com", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:51857/api/Account/GetRoleName/username@mail.com: 0 Unknown Error", error: abort }
```

[response from server side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pz2t5.png)

but when i test API in POSTMAN it's return a result correctly , also when i use Chrome Or Edge to test it with angular it works but not work in Firefox
my code in angular as below :

```
GetRoleName(email: string) {
    return this.http.get(this.url + 'GetRoleName/' + email, { responseType: 'text' });
  }


async installStorage(rem: boolean, email: string) {   
    this.GetRoleName(email).subscribe(success => {
      localStorage.setItem('role', this.service.Encrypt(success));
      console.log(success);
    }, err => console.log(err));
  }
```

role name can only be saved in chrome and Edge and worked correctly and no error appeared but it doesn't work in Firefox and show the above error,
if anyone can help me I have researched several times and I can't reach to answer.

Comment: Please supply ***all*** relevant information as text... ***especially*** error messages. When other people are searching for answers, it will be the error text that the are most likely searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A defect in one browser without the other is always caused by a conflict in the browser cache itself.
Search for cache data, wipe it, then try again, and you will find that the problem is gone

Comment: i have do that to clear cache from firefox browser but still show the error @abufahmi

Comment: Clear all cache data and cookies then try again